# How to use the GA4 API?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to use the GA4 API using PHP, but fail.

I follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries).

I'm assuming that the following command needs to run on the command line:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/credentials.json"
```

(I replace the file with my own, in what should be the correct location.)

I then run the sample script from the tutorial (using PHP, having installed the PHP API library via Composer), inserting my GA4 property ID.

I then get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught DomainException: Your default credentials were
> not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see
> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc

The [mentioned URL](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc) seems to not address my issue at all.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Are you able to see the events from your GA Dashboard?

Comment: Yes, all stats appear to work as they should. I included the email that was in the generated json as an account able to view the stats.

Comment: Is there any more code? What does "but fail" mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase: I fail to get this to work. I'm following the steps in the links provided (by Google), no customisation whatsoever (except using my own json with credentials, and my own GA4 property ID.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well and you want to read the events from GA4 using PHP, you can use the Google Analytics Data API. To read GA4 events related to 2 days ago (for example), follow these steps:

Make sure that the service account has appropriate permissions in your GA4 property.

**Install Google Client Library for PHP**:
you can manually download the library and include it in your project. Here's how you can do it:

1. **Download the library**:

   - Visit the [Google API PHP Client's GitHub repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client).
   - Click the green "Code" button and select "Download ZIP".
   - Extract the ZIP file after downloading.
2. **Include the library in your PHP project**:

   - Move the extracted `google-api-php-client` directory to your project's root directory or any other location within your project.
   - In your PHP script where you wish to use the Google API client, you will need to include the required files. Typically, this is done using an `autoload.php` file. For instance:

     ```php
     require 'path_to_google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
     ```

   Remember to replace `path_to_google-api-php-client` with the correct path to where you placed the library in your project.

**Read GA4 Events with PHP**:
Here's a PHP code example that reads GA4 events from 2 days ago:

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'city',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Google Analytics Data API (GA4) Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#php)

Make sure to replace 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID' with the actual ID of your GA4 property.

Please remember that this is a basic example, and there's much more you can do with the API, like adding filtering conditions, different metrics, etc.

Comment: Thanks. You understood me well. But this is not working for me. When I execute code like yours, I get the fatal error I mention. I note that you do not include a step that exports GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, which is where I think my problem hinges on.

Comment: The only credentials you need to import is the json file, which at line 3 I have called it account_key.json

Comment: Thanks. This starts to execute. But gives me "Warning: Undefined property: Google\Service\AnalyticsData::$v1alpha" on "$response = $analytics->v1alpha->runReport($request);".

Comment: Are you sure the proprrtyId you are using is correct? Do you know where you should find it in your analytics profile?

Comment: As sure as I can be. But, I get it from GA4, under 'Property settings'. It's near the top right of the screen, where it is prefaced by "Property ID".

Comment: @MastaBaba that is correct, now "Ensure Correct Library Version: Make sure you're using the correct version of the Google Analytics Data API client library for PHP" and I am going to update my code, check it please

Comment: Thanks. This now looks like the default example Google provides. And I get the error I got at first: "Uncaught DomainException: Your default credentials were not found.". As before, it seems to me that this centers on the instruction to 'export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/credentials.json"', but I do not understand where this is supposed to be added. Running this on the command line does nothing.

Comment: (Obviously, pointing to my own credentials file.)